# Manipulating strings in PHP

Tags: php

I have this variable that contains a string.
For example:

```
    $message    =   
    'Dear User1,

    Your record submitted has been disapproved by User.

    Remarks: 

    Document No.: 
    Record Title: Test1
    Record URL: http://myapp.dev/records?id=1

    Sincerely,

    Admin

    Dear User1,

    Your record submitted has been disapproved by User.

    Remarks: 

    Document No.: 
    Record Title: Test2
    Record URL: http://myapp.dev/records?id=2

    Sincerely,

    Admin';
```

What will I do in order to get this type of result?

```
    Dear User1,

    Your record submitted has been disapproved by User.

    Remarks: 

    Document No.: 
    Record Title: Test1
    Record URL: http://myapp.dev/records?id=1
    Record Title: Test2
    Record URL: http://myapp.dev/records?id=2

    Sincerely,

    Admin
```

I think I could manipulate the string by using `preg_split();`?

Please mention the things that I missed or you want to know. Any idea(s) would be really appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: use html for this type of output.

Comment: Okay, I will edit my question

Comment: Sorry to ask @AwladLiton, I didn't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better late than nothing. Try this function

```
function manipulate($text){
    $texts = preg_split("/(Remarks:|Sincerely,|Document No.:)/",$text,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $str = $texts[0];
    $str .= "Remarks: \n\nDocument No.:";
    for($x=0;$x<count($texts);$x++){
        if($texts[$x]=='Document No.:'){
            $str .= trim($texts[($x+1)],"\r\n");
        }   
    }
    $str.= "\n\nSincerely,\n\nAdmin";
    return $str;
}
```

if your using this one as html the use `nl2br()` like

```
nl2br(manipulate($message)); //where $message is your "Dear User1,...."
```

Comment: much appreciated man! this is awesome, I really need to improve though.

Answer (score 2):

use [`nl2br()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp) to get desired output.

```
echo nl2br($message);
```

Output

```
Dear User1,

Your record submitted has been disapproved by User.

Remarks: 

Document No.: 
Record Title: Test1
Record URL: http://myapp.dev/records?id=1

Sincerely,

Admin

Dear User1,

Your record submitted has been disapproved by User.

Remarks: 

Document No.: 
Record Title: Test2
Record URL: http://myapp.dev/records?id=2

Sincerely,

Admin
```

See [demo](https://eval.in/467527)

Comment: There are more functions I'm now discovering! Much appreciated!

Comment: it's a bit different output on the OP's expected output

Comment: But it's still progress, I think I can use this function I suppose.

Comment: ya... you can wrap things using `html tags`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to display in html page.
Have tryied with nl2br() ?

I think that it should be better to use heredoc syntax, such as:

```
$message = <<< EOT_MSG
    'Dear User1,
     ...
     ....
EOT_MSG;
```

Comment: nl2br() is new to me, I will have a look on that function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like [this](http://pastebin.com/hWnNbrG6), an alternative to heredoc.

Here you can find the library.
https://gist.github.com/fcamp/c4cb828cfb22bbe845cb